# Error while trying to print out multidimensional array - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing an assignment, where I need to take values from input.txt and print it out, so I thought the best way to do that is to store values into array. But I keep getting error whenever I try to access multidimentional array.

Code:

```
a = []
File.open("input.txt") do |f|

  f.each_line do |line|
    a << line.split.map
  end
end
puts "#{a[0][1]}"
```

input.txt file:

```
2015-02-01 S MR
2015-02-02 S MR
2015-02-03 L LP
2015-02-05 S LP
2015-02-06 S MR
2015-02-06 L LP
```

Error I get:[image: error_screenshot]

However if I just print out the whole array like

`puts a.inspect`
I get this: 
[image: everything_seems_working_right_here]

Where's the problem?

Comment: What was your intent with including `.map`?  Without the `.map` it will likely work.  It looks as though you may have planned on doing some other action to each array element but didn't pass a block to `.map` to define what that action should be.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I really don't even know, just stumbled upon some code in stackoverflow and copied it. BTW it now works !

Comment: You created an array of enumerators. You should read the documentation for `.map` carefully.

Comment: "stumbled upon some code in stackoverflow and copied it." Hey, at least try to understand what you copy!

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll copy some code I don't understand from Stack Overfllow.” Now they have two problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Don't use images to show us results or data; When the links break the question won't make sense. You have 8 lines of code and your error shows the error is on line 15. Please help us help you and present code that accurately duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` without a block will return an `Enumerator`. Just remove the `map` and your code will work.

That being said: the code you show does not make much sense. Splitting and then mapping without block does not do anything meaningful.

What is it you want to achieve?